# Does ag-grid (https://www.ag-grid.com) supports re-sizing of grid columns on mobile devices?

Tags: angularjs, frontend, ag-grid

I was planning to use ag-grid library in my project. I am looking for features sorting, pagination, filtering grouping and **Resizing** of grid columns, both on desktop and other devices.

I was analyzing **ag-grid** but I am not sure whether it provides **resize** functionality on **mobile devices** or not. 
Can someone please help me to know whether it support resizing grid columns or not and any other library which can be used with **angular 1.5.3**.

Comment: It doesn't appear to, no. I tried the resizing the grid in the [example page for resizing](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/example2.html) and it didn't work on my mobile device (smartphone). It appears [this](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/blob/c7d841ca837c3087e21c3e19a267cc51a956e7db/dist/lib/headerRendering/horizontalDragService.js#L20) is what's applied to the handle, so no mobile support I presume.... :(